# Access Form - instantiate it once

Tags: c#

After closing a form, I can't access it anymore, because the object does not exist anymore.
Is there a way to avoid this kind of behaviour, without initiating the object everytime I perform an event?
This is the first Form called status, it's not the only one I need to create, that's why Iam asking.

This does not work: After closing the form and click on the menu item I get an reference error "Object does not exist", and therefor can't be accessed.

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    StatusForm statusForm = new StatusForm();

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        statusForm.MdiParent = this;
    }

    private void statusToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        statusForm.Show();
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        statusForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Close` to close a form, it is unusable after that point. You *have* to create a new one.

However, if you want a persistent `Form` object, just call `Form.Hide` instead. This hides the form but leaves it "open".

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) notes this as well:

> When the Close method is called on a Form displayed as a modeless
>   window, you cannot call the Show method to make the form visible,
>   because the form's resources have already been released. To hide a
>   form and then make it visible, use the Control.Hide method.